# Is it possible to specify which primary key ActiveStorage should use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In defining an ActiveStorage "relation", you use the following:

```
# event.rb
class Event
  has_one_attached :cover_image
end
```

This uses `event.id` automatically.

My problem is that I'm in the middle of transitioning my models from `int` IDs to `UUID` ids.
Event is one of our foundational models so it's in between states. As a result, `event.id => int` and `event.guid => uuid`.

This isn't a problem for relations as I can just define `has_one :thing, primary_key: :guid` and it will work.

My ActiveStorage table is already using `uuid` ids & reference keys.

So, is there a way I can tell :cover_image to use :guid as its primary key instead?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61757321/is-it-possible-to-specify-which-primary-key-activestorage-should-use and https://gist.github.com/kylefox/00c3d9ca56df78282696ef6bfef5b2f4 might help

Comment: @Mark the first link is a link to this question 

Comment: You can have two types of pks at once since ActiveStorage puts all your blobs on a single table and links backs to the model with a polymorphic association.

Comment: There is no option in for `has_one_attached` to change the primary key but if you [take it apart](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ac30e389ecfa0e26e3d44c1eda8488ddf63b3ecc/activestorage/lib/active_storage/attached/macros.rb#L41) you can see that it generates two associations that you can override by redefining it underneath the call to `has_one_attached`. `has_one :"cover_image_attachment", -> { where(name: "cover_image") }, class_name: "ActiveStorage::Attachment", as: :record, inverse_of: :record, dependent: false, primary_key: :uuid`

Comment: Oops - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51531441/rails-5-2-activestorage-with-uuids-on-postgresql - basically states what you suggested

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a complete answer, but a workaround that I've used was defining the attachment as a separate model with the attachment and associating that model to `Event`.

Something like:

```
class EventCover
  has_one_attached :image
  belongs_to :event, primary_key: :guid
end

class Event
  has_one :event_cover
end
```